# How to intergrate <select> with <table>?

Tags: javascript, php, css, html-table

[Here is jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y5tZq/)

Is it possible, to make table react like select? I need to make product list where user chooses an element and then sends value from that table?

Putting `<table>` within `<select>` isn't what I am looking for because I can't show multiple columns like I want them to apear!

I don't want to use any jquery or similar things, because I need to keep it as simple as I can!

Comment: Let me get this straight, you want after the user clicks on a table he gets a select box?

Comment: I want the table react like size=n+1 select box, user selects <tr> and then fills out rest of the form and clicks submit. Basicly I would want a multi column `<select>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming i got that straight, what you need to do is wrap each row in anchor tags and set the onclick method to something you need

Comment: Well maybe I could set `onclick` event witch sets hidden value to something, but the point is, is it possible without that many js lines included? Because I don't how to set `<table><tr>` value...